Is it possible to enable a specific feature when another feature is disabled?
I have the following:
comfy-table = { version = "7.1.1", default-features = false }

[features]
wasm = []

I want:

when the wasm feature is not enabled the feature tty in comfy-table should be enabled; and
if wasm feature is enabled the feature tty in comfy-table should not be enabled.

Is it possible?

At the very least mutually exclusive features are very unidiomatic, I don't think there is a way to do it.

No, as features are additive, but there are two good alternatives. First, you could detect WebAssembly by using target_arch:
[target.'cfg(not(target_arch = "wasm32"))'.dependencies]
comfy-table = { version = "7.1.1", features = ["tty"], default-features = false }

[target.'cfg(target_arch = "wasm32")'.dependencies]
comfy-table = { version = "7.1.1", default-features = false }

(for completeness, note that you can try any(target_arch = "wasm32", target_arch = "wasm64") if the unstable 64-bit version of WebAssembly might be used)
Second, you could invert your feature:
comfy-table = { version = "7.1.1", default-features = false }

[features]
tty = ["comfy-table/tty"]

